# Как устроен auto

Tags: c++, c++11

Заинтересовался природой auto, но почему-то по нему как-то скудновато информации, все говорят что с ним можно сделать, а не как устроен.
Тогда я попытался [изучить](https://onlinegdb.com/VJo3qWAO5) сам.
Верно ли утверждение, что auto работает на этапе исполнения и создаёт переменную нужного типа, но тип она менять не может? Если да, то почему тогда не сделали auto который может принимать любой объект и по сути быть безтиповой переменной? Есть ли такое в плюсах?
Если auto работает на этапе исполнения, есть ли такой же аналог, только на этапе компиляции, какой-нибудь директивой препроцессора(конечно при условии, что никакой неопределённости не будет в начении)?

Comment: `auto` работает на этапе компиляции. Проверить просто: передайте переменную этого типа туда, где фактический её тип не принимают. Получите ошибку компиляции. Беcтиповая переменная - это `std::any`.

Comment: В вашем примере `a` имеет выведенный тип `char`. Он не меняется по ходу исполнения программы. При вызове `f2()` и `f3` вы помещаете в переменную типа `char` то, что char'ом не является. Однако здесь возможно приведение типов, которое выполняется автоматически.

Comment: а полиморфный объект из него можно делать? @maestro

Comment: Нуу, если у вас есть `class B : public A` и вы пишете `auto obj = new B`, то будет выведен тип `B*`, а не `A*`.

Comment: А вообще, полиморфизм обычно появляется в программах, когда правая рука не знает, что делает левая...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`auto` работает на этапе компиляции. Для проверки передайте переменную этого типа туда, где фактический её тип не принимают. Получите ошибку компиляции. Беcтиповая переменная - это `std::any`.
В вашем примере `a` имеет выведенный тип `char`. Он не меняется по ходу исполнения программы. При вызове `f2()` и `f3` вы помещаете в переменную типа `char` то, что `char'`ом не является. Однако здесь возможно приведение типов, которое выполняется автоматически.